# How to identify extracted obj file from response of autodesk model derivative API?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

In Model Derivative API (OBJ Extraction using DbIds), I retrieved OBJ URN using API. As Response shows below, it returns all children's URN for obj, mtl, and its zip. How do we identify the recent extraction as every child does have its own guid?

I have attached whole response JSON. What I am looking for is the second obj file which has extracted using several dbids like "17,19,21,22,23...". The first child obj was created long ago. How do I differentiate the new obj. As GUID's are different for every node. How do I identify which GUID.obj belongs to my desired extraction.

** Edited **
 I am looking for identifying extracted wavefronts object files( not objectids and name which gets from metadata). Suppose if I extracted 2 object files from one model, then after completion of object file geometry extraction job, 6 file gets generated and store in bucket.

1. first   .obj  (guid = /output/geometry/e72fa6b3-4fc2-3c86-8424-5d0755539c0d.obj)
2. first   .mtl
3. first   .zip
4. second  .obj
5. second  .mtl
6. second  .zip

Every file does have different GUID.Type as name. and those guid's are random and never shown while calling of extraction API or while getting its progress.

these are shown in below JSON file. Now suppose I extracted 10 different object files from one model. that means in bucket 30 new file URN will be generated.
And it is getting very hard to identify.

The Solution could have been if I extract obj geometry from model, I should get that particular obj, mtl, zips guid. IF I am getting only 3 ids then I can map those and download it from bucket. 
What is happening now is I am getting all obj's guid (suppose 30 ) after calling get manifest  [GET :urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/extract-geometry-from-source-file/) . And I am not understanding what obj file belong to which extraction.

```
{
  "type": "manifest",
  "hasThumbnail": "true",
  "status": "success",
  "progress": "complete",
  "region": "US",
  "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZXh0cmFjdC1hdXRvZGVzay1pby0yMDE3MnVvbm5paWJkd2t1Z25ydGVvZGFjN2FpeWhwdjdrd20vcm1lX2FkdmFuY2VkX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0Lm53ZA",
  "version": "1.0",
  "derivatives": [{
    "name": "rme_advanced_sample_project.nwd",
    "hasThumbnail": "true",
    "status": "success",
    "progress": "complete",
    "outputType": "svf",
    "children": [{
      "guid": "763d96f1-0812-451d-b3a1-a51a27eba53b",
      "name": "rme_advanced_sample_project.rvt",
      "hasThumbnail": "true",
      "role": "3d",
      "viewableID": "rme_advanced_sample_project.rvt",
      "progress": "complete",
      "useAsDefault": true,
      "status": "success",
      "type": "geometry",
      "children": [{
        "guid": "1e172e73-2305-4eb8-9954-eeab8217a8d3",
        "name": "Default",
        "hasThumbnail": "true",
        "role": "3d",
        "camera": [-86.09573364257812, -79.89456176757812, 139.12220764160156, 70.56798553466797, 76.76915740966797, -17.541505813598633, 0.40824830532073975, 0.40824830532073975, 0.8164966106414795, 1.664323329925537, 0.785398006439209, 1, 0],
        "useAsDefault": true,
        "status": "success",
        "type": "view",
        "children": [{
          "guid": "f2054c5f-10b8-457b-a927-23b69107dcd7",
          "role": "thumbnail",
          "mime": "image/png",
          "resolution": [100, 100],
          "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZXh0cmFjdC1hdXRvZGVzay1pby0yMDE3MnVvbm5paWJkd2t1Z25ydGVvZGFjN2FpeWhwdjdrd20vcm1lX2FkdmFuY2VkX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0Lm53ZA/output/0/0_100.png",
          "type": "resource"
        }, {
          "guid": "20625548-d014-4d29-8e50-4d61a1759a60",
          "role": "thumbnail",
          "mime": "image/png",
          "resolution": [200, 200],
          "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZXh0cmFjdC1hdXRvZGVzay1pby0yMDE3MnVvbm5paWJkd2t1Z25ydGVvZGFjN2FpeWhwdjdrd20vcm1lX2FkdmFuY2VkX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0Lm53ZA/output/0/0_200.png",
          "type": "resource"
        }, {
          "guid": "48675a6a-f2ec-4748-b22c-200b72cd06a8",
          "role": "thumbnail",
          "mime": "image/png",
          "resolution": [400, 400],
          "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZXh0cmFjdC1hdXRvZGVzay1pby0yMDE3MnVvbm5paWJkd2t1Z25ydGVvZGFjN2FpeWhwdjdrd20vcm1lX2FkdmFuY2VkX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0Lm53ZA/output/0/0_400.png",
          "type": "resource"
        }]
      }, {
        "guid": "77850512-9e8b-4d09-bb1a-45706ad5b7e6",
        "name": "3D View",
        "hasThumbnail": "false",
        "role": "viewable",
        "progress": "0% complete",
        "status": "success",
        "type": "folder",
        "children": [{
          "guid": "ebf9f756-6cfa-4858-9787-e3af9c8424c3",
          "name": "3D Duct & Equipment",
          "role": "3d",
          "camera": [61.56271743774414, 38.53883743286133, 9.783880233764648, 59.46215057373047, 40.639404296875, 7.683313846588135, -0.40824830532073975, 0.40824830532073975, 0.8164966106414795, 1, 45, 227.96743774414062, 1],
          "status": "success",
          "type": "view"
        }, {
          "guid": "54d5a270-f330-4446-a482-1079312d8518",
          "name": "Main Electrical Distribution",
          "role": "3d",
          "camera": [91.54497528076172, -63.42673110961914, -34.64605712890625, 46.680015563964844, 38.5232048034668, -66.7026596069336, -0.11140129715204239, 0.25314533710479736, 0.9609928131103516, 1, 45, 342.1146545410156, 1],
          "status": "success",
          "type": "view"
        }, {
          "guid": "2c6938f2-c052-4195-93d0-adc7af1cb965",
          "name": "3D Plumbing",
          "role": "3d",
          "camera": [3.6063644886016846, -184.62478637695312, 180.24473571777344, 173.09983825683594, -2.4171712398529053, -0.014680136926472187, 0.39955270290374756, 0.42952418327331543, 0.8098559379577637, 1, 45, 461.8291931152344, 1],
          "status": "success",
          "type": "view"
        }, {
          "guid": "1b3f6ae4-beb6-478c-9cfe-b83bf371141d",
          "name": "Room 53 3D Fire Protection",
          "role": "3d",
          "camera": [735.119384765625, -538.998779296875, 662.6300048828125, 98.2931900024414, 97.82740020751953, 25.80381202697754, -0.40824830532073975, 0.40824830532073975, 0.8164966106414795, 1, 45, 368.90972900390625, 1],
          "status": "success",
          "type": "view"
        }, {
          "guid": "45811cc4-79ed-421b-82b2-6c8548d1507e",
          "name": "WSHP 2-3 System View",
          "role": "3d",
          "camera": [108.588134765625, 117.7073974609375, 54.383365631103516, 102.33130645751953, 123.9642333984375, 48.12653350830078, -0.40824830532073975, 0.40824830532073975, 0.8164966106414795, 1, 45, 333.1808776855469, 1],
          "status": "success",
          "type": "view"
        }, {
          "guid": "8c1402a9-6af6-47af-af0d-2c025ca26109",
          "name": "Plumbing Isometric - Domestic Water",
          "role": "3d",
          "camera": [3.6063644886016846, -184.62478637695312, 180.24473571777344, 173.09983825683594, -2.4171712398529053, -0.014680136926472187, 0.39955270290374756, 0.42952418327331543, 0.8098559379577637, 1, 45, 461.8291931152344, 1],
          "status": "success",
          "type": "view"
        }, {
          "guid": "9dcc0f6a-fc2c-418f-8d08-c99b7afed337",
          "name": "Plumbing Isometric - Sanitary Waste",
          "role": "3d",
          "camera": [3.6063644886016846, -184.62478637695312, 180.24473571777344, 173.09983825683594, -2.4171712398529053, -0.014680136926472187, 0.39955270290374756, 0.42952418327331543, 0.8098559379577637, 1, 45, 461.8291931152344, 1],
          "status": "success",
          "type": "view"
        }, {
          "guid": "e3a2443a-7f4c-49dc-a41d-da067922ab04",
          "name": "Typical Make Up Air Isometric Detail",
          "role": "3d",
          "camera": [0.8279496431350708, 187.99771118164062, 118.81455993652344, 100.31283569335938, 88.51282501220703, 19.32967758178711, 0.40824830532073975, -0.40824830532073975, 0.8164966106414795, 1, 45, 248.74505615234375, 1],
          "status": "success",
          "type": "view"
        }, {
          "guid": "915564b9-ed83-426e-88df-002dac32363b",
          "name": "Typical Room WSHP",
          "role": "3d",
          "camera": [171.6078338623047, -3.038959264755249, 18.71452522277832, 90.31718444824219, 43.15993118286133, -21.66922950744629, -0.34472253918647766, 0.19591180980205536, 0.9180331826210022, 1, 45, 257.0640869140625, 1],
          "status": "success",
          "type": "view"
        }, {
          "guid": "12a3ef04-1364-4c23-af91-2679132e3848",
          "name": "Toilet Room",
          "role": "3d",
          "camera": [196.7369842529297, -4.305071830749512, 109.12708282470703, 98.9510269165039, 86.86759948730469, 14.070858001708984, -0.42381933331489563, 0.3951563239097595, 0.8150022625923157, 1, 45, 359.9964294433594, 1],
          "status": "success",
          "type": "view"
        }, {
          "guid": "9a34ab86-dfdf-4516-a087-b8f9775435fe",
          "name": "1st Level Slice",
          "role": "3d",
          "camera": [-76.2143325805664, -163.60708618164062, 175.46923828125, 111.73212432861328, 69.6202392578125, 11.465206146240234, 0.3013473451137543, 0.373949259519577, 0.8771269917488098, 1, 45, 313.0205993652344, 1],
          "status": "success",
          "type": "view"
        }, {
          "guid": "09effac0-27ac-4f02-b4d7-31ef18a57ef9",
          "name": "{3D}",
          "role": "3d",
          "camera": [0.8279496431350708, 187.99771118164062, 118.81455993652344, 100.31283569335938, 88.51282501220703, 19.32967758178711, 0.40824830532073975, -0.40824830532073975, 0.8164966106414795, 1, 45, 358.7159118652344, 1],
          "status": "success",
          "type": "view"
        }]
      }, {
        "guid": "f9f4721d-9304-43c4-8c07-34cbcc5e79c7",
        "role": "graphics",
        "mime": "application/autodesk-svf",
        "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZXh0cmFjdC1hdXRvZGVzay1pby0yMDE3MnVvbm5paWJkd2t1Z25ydGVvZGFjN2FpeWhwdjdrd20vcm1lX2FkdmFuY2VkX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0Lm53ZA/output/0/0.svf",
        "type": "resource"
      }]
    }, {
      "guid": "3b7195a7-17ec-4d80-b259-4e9df165f3fb",
      "role": "Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase",
      "mime": "application/autodesk-db",
      "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZXh0cmFjdC1hdXRvZGVzay1pby0yMDE3MnVvbm5paWJkd2t1Z25ydGVvZGFjN2FpeWhwdjdrd20vcm1lX2FkdmFuY2VkX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0Lm53ZA/output/0/properties.db",
      "status": "success",
      "type": "resource"
    }]
  }, {
    "hasThumbnail": "false",
    "status": "success",
    "progress": "complete",
    "outputType": "obj",
    "children": [{
      "guid": "22519ef5-9da5-35ca-bc70-b25b45e8f8fa",
      "role": "obj",
      "modelGuid": "f9f4721d-9304-43c4-8c07-34cbcc5e79c7",
      "objectIds": [547, 924, 942, 977],
      "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZXh0cmFjdC1hdXRvZGVzay1pby0yMDE3MnVvbm5paWJkd2t1Z25ydGVvZGFjN2FpeWhwdjdrd20vcm1lX2FkdmFuY2VkX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0Lm53ZA/output/geometry/e72fa6b3-4fc2-3c86-8424-5d0755539c0d.obj",
      "status": "success",
      "type": "resource"
    }, {
      "guid": "75401422-bb33-350a-aa10-05625504d6ca",
      "role": "obj",
      "modelGuid": "f9f4721d-9304-43c4-8c07-34cbcc5e79c7",
      "objectIds": [547, 924, 942, 977],
      "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZXh0cmFjdC1hdXRvZGVzay1pby0yMDE3MnVvbm5paWJkd2t1Z25ydGVvZGFjN2FpeWhwdjdrd20vcm1lX2FkdmFuY2VkX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0Lm53ZA/output/geometry/e72fa6b3-4fc2-3c86-8424-5d0755539c0d.mtl",
      "status": "success",
      "type": "resource"
    }, {
      "guid": "a4b9fb43-8525-3243-bde1-72797399e342",
      "role": "obj",
      "modelGuid": "f9f4721d-9304-43c4-8c07-34cbcc5e79c7",
      "objectIds": [547, 924, 942, 977],
      "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZXh0cmFjdC1hdXRvZGVzay1pby0yMDE3MnVvbm5paWJkd2t1Z25ydGVvZGFjN2FpeWhwdjdrd20vcm1lX2FkdmFuY2VkX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0Lm53ZA/output/geometry/e72fa6b3-4fc2-3c86-8424-5d0755539c0d.zip",
      "status": "success",
      "type": "resource"
    }, {
      "guid": "1177e7ea-7fad-34b7-a7bd-23d70e4a62a8",
      "type": "resource",
      "role": "obj",
      "modelGuid": "f9f4721d-9304-43c4-8c07-34cbcc5e79c7",
      "objectIds": [17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 83, 84, 85, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 263, 264, 265, 268, 269, 270, 302, 303, 304, 320, 321, 322, 350, 351, 352, 370, 371],
      "status": "success",
      "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZXh0cmFjdC1hdXRvZGVzay1pby0yMDE3MnVvbm5paWJkd2t1Z25ydGVvZGFjN2FpeWhwdjdrd20vcm1lX2FkdmFuY2VkX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0Lm53ZA/output/geometry/a08e65e7-082a-3ce1-8116-ae534c9f081d.obj"
    }, {
      "guid": "61acd067-4637-3549-9bd3-cd362a4fb93b",
      "type": "resource",
      "role": "obj",
      "modelGuid": "f9f4721d-9304-43c4-8c07-34cbcc5e79c7",
      "objectIds": [17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 83, 84, 85, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 263, 264, 265, 268, 269, 270, 302, 303, 304, 320, 321, 322, 350, 351, 352, 370, 371],
      "status": "success",
      "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZXh0cmFjdC1hdXRvZGVzay1pby0yMDE3MnVvbm5paWJkd2t1Z25ydGVvZGFjN2FpeWhwdjdrd20vcm1lX2FkdmFuY2VkX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0Lm53ZA/output/geometry/a08e65e7-082a-3ce1-8116-ae534c9f081d.mtl"
    }, {
      "guid": "6c73254c-7bbf-312a-a481-aaeebdf53de3",
      "type": "resource",
      "role": "obj",
      "modelGuid": "f9f4721d-9304-43c4-8c07-34cbcc5e79c7",
      "objectIds": [17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 83, 84, 85, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 263, 264, 265, 268, 269, 270, 302, 303, 304, 320, 321, 322, 350, 351, 352, 370, 371],
      "status": "success",
      "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZXh0cmFjdC1hdXRvZGVzay1pby0yMDE3MnVvbm5paWJkd2t1Z25ydGVvZGFjN2FpeWhwdjdrd20vcm1lX2FkdmFuY2VkX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0Lm53ZA/output/geometry/a08e65e7-082a-3ce1-8116-ae534c9f081d.zip"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [GET :urn/metadata](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET/) to obtain a list of model views:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "metadata",
    "metadata": [
      {
        "name": "Scene",
        "role": "3d",
        "guid": "4f981e94-8241-4eaf-b08b-cd337c6b8b1f",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sheet: A101",
        "role": "2d",
        "guid": "8e7c6bca-cfd1-290e-4b16-f3670169bb71"
      }
    ]
   }
}
```

Then use [GET :urn/metadata/:guid](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-GET/) to retrieve the object tree to identify your derivatives:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "objects",
    "objects": [
      {
        "objectid": 1,
        "name": "A5",
        "objects": [
          {
            "objectid": 2,
            "name": "Model",
            "objects": [
              {
                "objectid": 3,
                "name": "Bottom",
                "objects": [
                  {
                    "objectid": 4,
                    "name": "Box"
                  }
                ]
              },
```

Comment: Hello @Bryan . Thank you for the reply. But I am looking for something else.
This gives us all object ID's and its name like model tree. I am looking for identifying extracted wavefronts object file. If I extracted 2 object files from one model, then after completion of obj extraction job, 6 file gets added. 1. first .obj 2.first.mtl 3.first.zip 4. second.obj 5. second.mtl 6.second.zip. As shown in JSON file. Now suppose I extracted 10 different object files from one model. that means in bucket 30 new file URN will be generated.

Comment: So If I want to see what was 9th object file. I do not have handle as GUID does not match.

Comment: I have Edited the question. Can you please look and reply soon.

Comment: If you've shared the entire manifest payload then there's only two sets of obj/mtl/zip (the rest are thumbnails and views) and you can either identify them by their name with the `GET :urn/metadata` endpoint or mapping them to objectIDs `[547, 924, 942, 977]` and `[17, 19, 21 ...` to cross-reference their details and figure out their identities.